# Persistant effects of modifying process environment via system

Tags: perl

I am making a few calls to the system, mainly `cd` commands, as certain functions need to called from certain directories on my system. However, I have noticed that once a call is finished, the effects of that call are lost.

For example, lets say that I start in `/home/project` and then call:

```
 system("setenv home/project/env/NeededEnvironment");
 system("make cfile.o");
```

The second system call doesn’t know about the first call setting the environment needed for the file to compile. I have tried putting them into one system call separated by `;` as well, but have the same problem. Is there anyway to get the effect of the first call to be saved?

Comment: If your goal is to string together a bunch of shell commands, use a shell script. If there is more to your script, use other Perl commands than system every once in a while.

Comment: Is the first command missing the name of an environment variable?

Comment: @GregBacon No, I just gave generic names because I am working on a system with its own commands for setting environments. the first call got and set the environment just fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is how `system` works: it creates a subshell to execute your command, and when the command is complete, the subshell exits leaving your `perl` process unaffected.

[Section 8 of the Perl FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.3/perlfaq8.html) also answers this question.

> #### I {changed directory, modified my environment} in a perl script. How come the change disappeared when I exited the script? How do I get my changes to be visible?
>
> - Unix
>
> In the strictest sense, it can't be done—the script executes as a different process from the shell it was started from. Changes to a process are not reflected in its parent—only in any children created after the change. There is shell magic that may allow you to fake it by [`eval()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html)ing the script's output in your shell; check out the [comp.unix.questions FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/unix/intro/) for details.

You want code along the lines of

```
system("cd /home/project/env/NeededEnvironment && make cfile.o") == 0
  or warn "$0: make failed";
```

or use the `-C` option to `make` and avoid shell argument parsing as in

```
system("make", "-C", "/home/project/env/NeededEnvironment", "cfile.o") == 0
  or warn "$0: make failed";
```

Comment: Ah, so the && between the two calls will make the second know about the effects of the first?

Comment: @NicholasKlein `&&` is a shell operator that means “run the first command and, if it succeeds, run the second.” The `cd` and `make` commands both execute in the same shell, so `make` executes with the working directory set by the prior `cd`.

Answer (score 7):

If you are writing a Perl script, use Perl itself and shell-out as rarely as possible.

If you need to change your directory:

```
chdir 'some/other/dir';
```

If you need to set an environment variable:

```
$ENV{ SOME_VAR } = 'Some value';
```

**Update**

Here are some more commands where the shell equivalent should not be used:

- `mkdir`
- `unlink`
- `rmdir`

Modules everyone should know about:

- `File::Copy`
- `File::Path`
- `File::Basename`
- `File::Spec`

Comment: +1 for "shell-out as rarely as possible", with clear examples

Comment: You should test whether `chdir` (or any system call) succeeds and give a helpful warning on failure.

Comment: Also, there's `File::Basename` and `File::Spec` for manipulation file & directory paths.

Comment: shawnhcorey: Good ones! I added them to the answer. A `basename` in backticks is something often encountered here on so.